# Loop thru selected directories in a particular order (Powershell)

Tags: powershell

I have this code that creates a sql script that contains a list of filenames from selected directories. It works. However, I am looking for ways to improve it. Instead of repeating Get-ChildItem block for each directory I would like to loop through selected directories in a particular order.

For example, I only want filenames from the following directories:
schemas,
sequences, and
functions
(want to ignore the rest)

I also need filenames in a particular order: first - filenames from "schemas", then from "functions" and then from "sequences".

Is there a way to do it? Or, it is better to keep what I have now?

```
$suffix = ":r ""$CurrentDir\$DeleteTempTableScript""`r`nGO"

(Get-ChildItem $TFSDirectory"Schemas" -Filter *.sql -Recurse).FullName |
        ForEach-Object {
            "PRINT '$_'"
            "GO"
            ":r ""$_"""
            "GO"
            $suffix
        } | Set-Content -Path $MasterSQLFileName -Encoding UTF8

(Get-ChildItem $TFSDirectory"Functions" -Filter *.sql -Recurse).FullName |
            ForEach-Object {
                "PRINT '$_'"
                "GO"
                ":r ""$_"""
                "GO"
                $suffix
            } | Add-Content -Path $MasterSQLFileName -Encoding UTF8

(Get-ChildItem $TFSDirectory"Sequences" -Filter *.sql -Recurse).FullName |
        ForEach-Object {
            "PRINT '$_'"
            "GO"
            ":r ""$_"""
            "GO"
            $suffix
        } | Add-Content -Path $MasterSQLFileName -Encoding UTF8
```

Comment: What is `$suffix`?

Comment: Added it to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of options. You could keep it simple and just add another loop. It will run in the order you put them. By making the outer loop a `Foreach-Object` loop you can still use the pipeline and do one `Set-Content`. The innerloop being a foreach statement is just preference.

```
"Schemas","Functions","Sequences" | ForEach-Object {
    Foreach($filepath in (Get-ChildItem $TFSDirectory$_ -Filter *.sql -Recurse).FullName)
    {
        "PRINT ""$filepath"""
        "GO"
        ":r ""$filepath"""
        "GO"
        $suffix
    }
} | Set-Content -Path $MasterSQLFileName -Encoding UTF8
```

Another option would be turn it into a function

```
Function New-SQLStatement {
    Param($Folder,$suffix)

    (Get-ChildItem $Folder -Filter *.sql -Recurse).FullName |
        ForEach-Object {
            "PRINT ""$_"""
            "GO"
            ":r ""$_"""
            "GO"
            $suffix
        }
}

"Schemas","Functions","Sequences" |
    ForEach-Object {New-SQLStatement -Folder $TFSDirectory$_ -suffix $suffix} |
        Set-Content -Path $MasterSQLFileName -Encoding UTF8
```

Answer (score 2):

The Path parameter accepts an array of strings, so you can do:

```
Get-ChildItem $TFSDirectory"Schemas", $TFSDirectory"Functions", $TFSDirectory"Sequences"
```